# Run a dll of application through C#

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, dll, console-application

I am trying to call a dll file that accepts command line arguments through c# code.

when I tried directly from cmd window it works but if I try to call this from C# it is showing following error : "No application is associated with the specified file for this operation"

sample cmd command - C:\Users\user name\source\repos\addconsole\addconsole\bin\Debug\netcoreapp3.1>dotnet AddConsole.dll 1 2 3

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
 {
   var proc1 = new ProcessStartInfo();
   proc1.UseShellExecute = true;
   proc1.WorkingDirectory = @"C:\Users\user name\source\repos\addconsole\addconsole\bin\Debug\netcoreapp3.1";
   proc1.FileName = @"addconsole.dll";
   proc1.Arguments = "1 2 3";
   Process.Start(proc1);
 }
```

Need help on this.please note there is no exe file this application that needs to be called has a dll file which has main function that executes the operation.

Comment: You could do run it using dotnet as you're already doing? Or, since this is already in .NET, as long as you're using a compatible framework you could load the assembly into a new appdomain and then start it by reflection?

Comment: Offtopic, I know, but "_a dll file that accepts command line arguments through c# code_" ...I wonder whose idea was that, what is the reasoning behind.

Comment: Currently the dll file that needs to be called is used like a console. My requirement is to  make it an web-api but also retain it as a console type app when needed. so if I pass command line and if args.count > 0 i will take them or prompt user to enter input via console.writline.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You actually need to call `dotnet.exe` and provide the relevant arguments. So set the FileName to dotnet and the rest as arguments.

```
var proc1 = new ProcessStartInfo();
proc1.UseShellExecute = true;
proc1.WorkingDirectory = @"C:\Users\user name\source\repos\addconsole\addconsole\bin\Debug\netcoreapp3.1";
proc1.Arguments = "\"addconsole.dll\" 1 2 3";
proc1.FileName = "dotnet.exe";
Process.Start(proc1);
```

Comment: Perfect..this works just modified dotnet to "dotnet.exe". Thanks a lot. suggesting to change code line in answer.